# Cannot install package pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

When i try pip install pyautogui it is not working
I have also used pip3 install pyautogui. And run in admininistrator

This is the error i get.

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Toegang geweigerd
Check the permissions

Comment: Self explained: You can run CMD in admin perm.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open CMD as administrator
2. write the following code:

```
python -m pip install pydirectory
```

enter,

```
python -m pip install pillow
```

enter,

```
python -m pip install pyautogui --upgrade
```

enter and enjoy!